# Program type already present: info.hoang8f.fbutton.BuildConfig

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

My project can't build properly when i update my Gradle to latest version.

This is my error log.

```
Program type already present: info.hoang8f.fbutton.BuildConfig
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: 
info.hoang8f.fbutton.BuildConfig, sources=[Unknown source file], tool 
name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

Comment: java, javasscript and c++ in the one program!!! try choosing the actual language you have a problem with, rather than tag spamming

Comment: Please  post much info about your build.gradle file for module and project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple dex files define <my package>/BuildConfig, can't find the cause:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103288/multiple-dex-files-define-my-package-buildconfig-cant-find-the-cause)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues and in my case the problem was that I used the same package name in two modules. I'm actually building a library and I think this is also the case for you: See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26531074/3734116

The error message just changed as Android Studio now uses the new D8 compiler instead of dx